# Why does another executable file doesn't give me a hint just like the other one on how parameters in command-line should be formatted?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, command-line-arguments, createprocess

In one of my executable file when I try to call it using CreateProcess and passed some parameters in command line the executable file gives me a hint that the parameter should be like this format.

[image: Image1]

But, when I try to call another executable it doesn't give me a hint. Any idea?

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: This has nothing to do with `CreateProcess`.  Programs can do whatever they want when they get an invalid command line.  Some give you some sort of usage hint, others just fail silently.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan The question is that "why my another executable file doesn't give me a hint just like the first one of how should parameters in command-line should be formatted."

Comment: @MilesBudnek do you have idea how to feed the parameters to another exe file? Coz when I try CreateProcess the exe file replies me with a usage hint.

Comment: It depends on the other program. Read the documentation. And if that's your question, please edit it to say so.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've re-phrased the question. Thanks.

Comment: When I call my friend's name and don't say anything he says "what?". But when I call my brother's name he doesn't say "what?". Any idea?

Comment: @immibis With all the respect sir. Do you know what command-line arguments are? CreateProcess function? Have you tried feeding some parameters from your source code to another executable file by using command-line in windows api CreateProcess?

Comment: This is not a programming question. Voted to close.

Comment: @IInspectable But that is related to `CreateProcess` function of windows api. Truly, the image above was a reply from the application I was called using `CreateProcess`. I have succesfully fed up my command-line parameters to another program just by calling it the `CreateProcess( "Path of executable file", "parameter1 parameter2"...)` which indeed a part of programming field itself. :)

Comment: This is unrelated to `CreateProcess`. You could just as well use `ShellExecuteEx`, or the Windows Command Prompt to see the same result. This is really asking about general computing, whether you use the insights gained from an answer in a call to `CreateProcess` or not. This is not a programming question (and complete lack of code in the question is a strong indication).

Comment: Why is this question tagged with `c++`?

Comment: @Eljay Actually, I'm integrating windows api in C++ right now. While coding, that scenario came to my mind. :)

Comment: @IInspectable Intentionally, I haven't posted my code because my code running well on the required program (.exe file). This scenario is only assumption if all programs had a standard interface on accessing their command-line arguments format. :)

Comment: There is a standard interface for applications on Windows to access the command-line passed to a process: [GetCommandLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156.aspx). This is unrelated to `CreateProcess`. This is also unrelated to the fact, that applications can respond to command-line arguments in any way they wish, or ignore them altogether. This is not a programming question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no requirement for an application to self document its command line arguments by way of console output or a dialog. Whether or not an application does so is entirely up the the author of that application.

Clearly you have two applications, one which shows a dialog, and one which doesn't. For the latter, presumably you must read its documentation to find out what the arguments should be.

Comment: https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/understanding-command-line-arguments-and-how-to-use-them/ This one also helps me a lot. :)

Answer (score -1):

Usage hint depends on the author of the application on how he expose the command-line format. In windows product you can use arguments like: `/? -? /help -help`

This link will give some information.
https://www.bleepingcomputer.com/tutorials/understanding-command-line-arguments-and-how-to-use-them/

Comment: The one who downvoted this link doesn't take time to read the article. it says there, that it depends on the author of the application on how he expose the format. In windows product you can use arguments like:   `/? -? /help -help`

Comment: The link isn't downvoted. The answer is. As a guide, link only answers are generally not recommended here. At the least you should summarise the key points and include the link for those that want to dig deeper.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan I've edited my answer. :)